# Asp.net Core - One-To-Many Relationship between an IdentityUser class and a custom defined class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, one-to-many, entity-framework-core

I have an issue regarding a navigation property that cannot be mapped, I have an Identity Use class defined as follow :

```
public partial class User: IdentityUser
{
    public User() : base()
    {
        this.Blog= new HashSet<Blog>();
    }

    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs{ get; set; }
}
```

And a Blog class like follow :

```
public partial class Blog : BaseModel
{        
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User{ get; set; }
}
```

In the IdentityDbContext I have overriden the OnModelCreating method like this :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasOne(b => b.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Blogs);
}
```

Seeded the database with custom data like this :

```
var usr1 = new User()
{
    Email = "colab1@emai.l",
    Nom = "CollaborateurNom",
    Prenom = "CollaborateurPrenom"
};
var userResult = await usrMgr.CreateAsync(usr1, "P@ssw0rd!");

Blog blg1 = new Blog()
{
    User = usr1
};

await ctx.SaveAsync();
```

In the database, I get the User attribute in Blog as null,
I know I have missed something, just don't know what it is exactly, please help!

**[UPDATE]**

Noticed lately that it's something that might be probably with the asynchronous creation of the User rows in the database, might be trying to add a user that is not already in the database, but still don't know how to make sure the user is already in the database before trying to assign it to a blog entry.

Comment: might just be a typo on stack overflow but your model Blog has a User named UserId and a string named UserId.  Should not be allowed to name two properties with the same name.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLee for your feedback, yes it was just a typo in stackoverflow!

Comment: I would try to create a new ICollection of Blog in your usr1 variable and initializing it that way.

Comment: You could also try to find your usr1 in your db and checking if it is in there before using it in your Blog.

Comment: I included the second option as an answer, please review and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.